# MongoDB start ID and end ID

Tags: mongodb, auto-increment, bulk-insert

I want to insert bulk data into a MongoDB.
Later on I want to find exactly the bulk I inserted.

In MySQL I would have done:

```
 SELECT * FROM data WHERE id >= start_id AND id <= end_id
```

How can I fix this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

If you know start _id and end _id then you can retrieve the bulk you inserted using query like this:

```
db.yourCollection.find({_id:{$gt:ObjectId("56e13d5aed63a8477a7e2e78"), $lt: ObjectId("570f5a27b2d1a50996d3a0f0")}})
```

Replace the default mongodb ObjectIds with your _id fields.

Also, if the _id you are using is default mongodb ObjectId then you can easily compare them using above query since mongodb [ObjectIds](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) are monotonically increasing.